# Expected non-nullable value for MutableLiveData

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, android-livedata, kotlin-null-safety

```
private val _users = MutableLiveData<List<User>>()
val users: LiveData<List<User>> get() = _users

fun getUsers() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        _users.value = users()
    }
}

suspend fun users(): List<User> {
    TODO("Not implemented")
}
```

I get following error on `_users.value = users()`

> Expected non-nullable value. Inspection info:
> This check ensures that LiveData values are not null when explicitly declared as non-nullable.

I'm using lifecycle version `2.3.1`. The problem seems to be with suspend function users(). If I remove the suspend modifier it works fine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use

```
private val _users: MutableLiveData<List<User>> = MutableLiveData()
```

instead of

```
private val _users = MutableLiveData<List<User>>()
```

Comment: These should be equivalent meaning. It appears to be an Android Lint bug. Do you know if this is documented anywhere or reported on the AOSP bug tracker?

Comment: No, I dont find any documentation yet, but I use this to get rid of error.

Comment: It is weird, also ````_users.postValue(users())```` made it runnable without error.

Comment: This didn't work for me..  The answer below did however.

Answer (score 11):

Try `this._users.value = users()`. Adding `this` at the front works for me. Not sure why. In your case you might need `this@yourModel._users.value = users()` since you are calling it in the viewModelScope.

Comment: This worked for me - the updated IDE has started to flag these, when it didn't before (also when updating LiveData in my ViewModels)..